# C fscanf reports EOF if parsed for a digit but not for a string

Tags: c, formatting, printf, scanf

I have the following line of text left in a file that I wish to parse one digit by one digit:

```
10001111001000101001010001100000101110000102
```

however when I use the format specifier %d fscanf returns an EOF indicator and not a digit. This is contrasted to when I use %s where it returns what I expect though it does it all at once and in a string.

So when I change (as well as the type of he from int to char[250])

```
if (fscanf(f, "%d", &character) != EOF)
```

to

```
if (fscanf(f, "%s", &character) != EOF)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to scan digit by digit, you need to use `"%1d"` as the format.

Otherwise, it reads the whole line (apart from the newline) as the number and invokes undefined behaviour when it converts the large decimal number into a 32-bit `int`.  Note that the mnemonic for `d` is not 'digit' but 'decimal', as opposed to 'o' for octal, 'x' for hexadecimal, and 'i' for integer in decimal, octal or hexadecimal according to the normal prefixes (leading `0` for octal, `0x` for hex, or decimal otherwise).

It is still not entirely clear why it returns EOF, but with undefined behaviour, any response is valid.

The standard (ISO/IEC 9898:2011 Section 7.21.6.2 **The `fscanf()` function**, Para 10) says (in the relevant part):

> If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

There is quite a lot of verbiage about the behaviour under error conditions, but this is the crucial one here.  Since the behaviour is undefined, getting EOF is a valid and relatively benign response.  It would be interesting to investigate whether the file stream is in the state where `feof(f)` or `ferror(f)` returns true.  There's no obvious reason why it should be except that you do not normally get EOF from `fscanf()` unless one or the other is true.

Comment: Presumably it returned EOF because it was unable to convert the input to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`"%d"` format-specifier inside a `scanf` family function will cause the function to look for a digit sequence, that is terminated with the first non-digit character encounter. In your case, using `"%d"` will consume up all the digits at once.

If `"%d"` didn't do as such, then you'd only be able to read single-digit numbers with it, which would be barely any formatted-input.

`"%s"` format-specifier causes a character sequence to get consumed, which is to get terminated with a white-space character, or end of file.

What you are looking for here, is to read the input character-by-character. You can do that with `"%c"` format-specifier. Afterwards, you can interpret the obtained character to its digital value.

For example; you could read the first `'1'` character, then subtract a `'0'` character from it, which would yield `'1' - '0' == 1`, the thing you seem to want.

Comment: Thats what I thought and I guess was trying to avoid it, I guess it goes to show you don't be as clever as you can coding because debugging requires two times the cleverness.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` returns the number of input items assigned or `EOF` in the case of failure.  That is only one problem.  The other is that it will continue to consume characters from the input string until it encounters a `\0` character or a non-digit (in the `%d` case).  Passing it the address of a single character is not a valid thing to do either.  You could do something like the following instead:

```
char *p;
for (p=&input_string[0]; isdigit(*p); p++) {
    int digit = (int)(*p - '0');
    /* process digit */
}
```

If you want to use one of the `scanf` functions, create a string of two characters - the digit being processed and `\0`.  Then `sscanf` that.

Comment: From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ it says "On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.
"

Comment: It returns the number of input items assigned, or `EOF` if an input failure occurs before any were assigned.

Comment: Yes which is why I am checking for EOF

Comment: Sorry bout that … haven't done C in about 10 years.  Corrected now.